# Trace flags 1117 and 1118 discontinued. does this mean it's not working anymore?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I was messing around on our servers and I could see that theres a lot of servers using T1117 and T1118 as a startup parameter.

but I remember ( and I just read some posts from pinal ) that they're discontinued.

I noticed that because I saw in the SQL Server log the message that these trace files are discontinued.

Does this mean that they don't work anymore? or it will not receive updates and etc?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really quick [google search](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-t1117-and-t1118-changes-for-tempdb/ba-p/318699):

> One of these changes is TEMPDB always assumes -T1117 and -T1118 behavior. ... In summary, SQL Server 2016 no longer requires one to turn on TF 1117 or 1118.